# opengl: question about glutMainLoop()

Tags: c, opengl, graphics, glut

can somebody explain how does `glutMainLoop` work?
and second question, why `glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);` defined
after `glutDisplayFunc(RenderScene);` cause firstly we call `glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);`
and only then define `glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);`

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
    {
        glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);
        glutInitWindowSize(800, 00);
        glutInitWindowPosition(300,50);
    glutCreateWindow("GLRect");
    glutDisplayFunc(RenderScene);
        glutReshapeFunc(ChangeSize);
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);  <--
    glutMainLoop();

        return 0;
    }

void RenderScene(void)
    {
    // Clear the window with current clearing color
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    // Set current drawing color to red
    //         R     G     B
    glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

    // Draw a filled rectangle with current color
    glRectf(0.0f, 0.0f, 50.0f, -50.0f);

    // Flush drawing commands
    glFlush();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`glutMainLoop()` just runs a platform-specific event loop and calls any registered `glut*Func()` callbacks as needed.

`RenderScene()` won't be called by GLUT until you call `glutMainLoop()`.  So in reality `glClearColor()` gets called first, not `glClear()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
glutDisplayFunc(RenderScene);
```

This only sets the callback function, it doesn't actually call it until it enters the main app loop in the call to `glutMainLoop`.  So `glClearColor` comes before `glClear`.