# Call function from within glutMainLoop()

Tags: c++, c, opengl, glut

Is there a way to call a function with parameters from within glutMainLoop()?  I have a simulation that with each step updates a vertex array...

Specifically, I was looking at glutIdleFunc() as a solution, but it doesn't seem to accept parameters.  I could make my arrays global, but I really don't want to do that....

Comment: Don't use glut, if it doesn't suit your needs.

Comment: You can hide glut callback api by wrapping it in your own api. glut is simple enough to do so. With C++ you can make a fully generic and type safe binding. Writing a message passing api is another solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think you stumbled over the dark side of 3d Programming :).

1st of all , glutIdleFunc() should be avoided , so don't go there to look for a solution.

You will need to research a bit about openGL and how it handles it's C functions.
These 2 topics might be relevant.

[opengl glutmainloop()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1862496/opengl-glutmainloop)

[opengl: question about glutMainLoop()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2898357/opengl-question-about-glutmainloop)

Hope it helps clear some things out.